# Javascript How to create delay in FOR loop

Tags: javascript, loops

Im trying to add a SetTimeOut to a loop but it fails to pause the code Im trying to insert the SetTimeOut to is:

```
    var temp  = new Array();
    var l = 1; 
    for (var i=coreLines.length-1; i>=0; i--) { 
        l += 1 + Math.floor(coreLines[i].length/displayCols);
        if (l >= displayRows) break
        else temp.push(coreLines[i]);
    }
```

Comment: You should call `setTimeOut()` recursively...`setTimeOut()` should replace your loop.

Comment: A more appropriate duplicate may be this one - [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)

Comment: how u gona pick a duplicate that has duplicates itself and is about a whole nother programming language.. that needs to be changed.

Comment: what i cant seem to get my head around is how to incorp the if else..